# Reading keystore.p12:Private key not stored as PKCS#8 EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo: java.io.IOException: overrun, bytes = 261

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, pkcs#12

I've a .p12 keystore which is having Entry type: SecretKeyEntry. If I try to read the keystore getting error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Private key not stored as PKCS#8 EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo: java.io.IOException: overrun, bytes = 261
at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:373)
at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:90)
at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1057)
at client.Keystest.main(Keystest.java:25)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: overrun, bytes = 261
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:77)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:362)
    ... 3 more
```

If I try to convert the keystore from PKCS12 to JKS getting same error

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.ks -deststoretype PKCS12
Importing keystore keystore.p12 to keystore.ks...
Enter destination keystore password:
Enter source keystore password:
keytool error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Private key not stored as PKCS#8 EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo: java.io.IOException: overrun, bytes = 261
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Private key not stored as PKCS#8 EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo: java.io.IOException: overrun, bytes = 261
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:373)
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetEntry(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1346)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetEntry(KeyStoreDelegator.java:166)
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(KeyStore.java:1555)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.recoverEntry(Main.java:3536)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doImportKeyStoreSingle(Main.java:2253)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doImportKeyStoreAll(Main.java:2303)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doImportKeyStore(Main.java:2195)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1189)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:398)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:391)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: overrun, bytes = 261
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:77)
        at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:362)
        ... 10 more
```

Not getting the exact cause for "overrun, bytes = 261"

Comment: (1) how was this P12 created (e.g. with what software and commands/options, or device)? (2) can you provide an example file with the problem, as hex or base64 or somewhere like pastebin -- i.e. can you reproduce with a key whose security doesn't matter? (3) even if you could or can read this, you won't be able to convert it to JKS, because JKS can't contain a SecretKeyEntry

Comment: Thanks Dave, I used orapki (Oracle wallet) tool to generate the keystore file. Using keytool am not able to convert to JKS but after exploring orapki tool, found option pkcs12_to_jks, after converting to JKS the keystore entrytype is changed to PrivateKeyEntry. Now able to read the keystore from JKS file. But not sure why am not able to read the data from wallet generated keystore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was with the Java version. Setting JAVA_HOME to point to Java 8 before running keytool did the trick:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@8
$ keytool -v -importkeystore ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Either use a more recent java version or a different security provider.
E.g. [bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html)bouncycastle will do the job and you are going to use the [bouncycastle provider for JDK 8 and later](https://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk18on-172.jar)

To enable it you either modify the file `jre/lib/security/java.security` in your JDK 8 and put that provider at position 1:

```
security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
security.provider.2=sun.security.provider.Sun
...
```

or you add it once at runtime at position 1:

```
BouncyCastleProvider bouncyCastleProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
Security.insertProviderAt(bouncyCastleProvider, 1);
```